# How can I ensure that the subdirectory name never appears in the URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to make my base directory neater by moving my primary website's content into its own subfolder. However, I don't want that subfolder name to *ever* appear in the URL (ideally). It should seem like nothing has changed. I've browsed other similar questions on StackOverflow but they haven't solved my problem (see below).

So far, I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sub/index.html [L]
```

With this in place, if I navigate to `domain.com/`, I see the contents of `sub` as expected, and nothing else in the URL. All good so far.

**The Problem**

The problem occurs when I try to navigate to a URL like `domain.com/folder` *without* the trailing slash. The final URL ends up as `domain.com/sub/folder`. I don't want `sub` in there, anywhere, ever. What should I add to the .htaccess file so that `sub` stays hidden in every case?

If I add the trailing slash like `domain.com/folder/`, then `sub` stays hidden as desired. It's only without the trailing slash that the issue occurs.

Comment: FYI, tried to use http://htaccess.mwl.be/ and http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/, but they don't address the URL hiding issue. Good luck, I'll come back to this if a UNIX whiz hasn't answered in the meantime...

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /sub/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ sub/index.html [L]
```

Comment: This worked! Could you explain how you came up with this solution (for a novice if you can)?